# No response was received. Either the request could not be opened or the request timed out ( for POST request )

Tags: web-services, rest, post, restful-url, poster

I have a request which works fine when i hit the service using POSTMAN and POSTER plugins but when i try to hit load-balancing url i received ERROR.

**ERROR in POSTER** ( plugin ):

[image]

**ERROR in POSTMAN** ( plugin ):

[image]

*Part of code:*

```
@Path( "/" )
public class Check {
     public ResultSet rs;

     @POST
     @Produces( MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN )
     @Consumes( "application/xml" )
     public String validate( String xmlContent ) throws Exception {
          String value = "no";
          String result = null;
          Boolean inputCheck;

          Contents unmarshalledValues = unmarshalingContent( xmlContent );
```

**MIME Type Details:**

Well, MIME type of xml

http://annevankesteren.nl/2004/08/mime-types

**Example for consuming XML**

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkknj.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have JAXRS to un-marshaller xml, so i removed

```
@Consumes
```

it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi @MadD can you try so like this,

```
@Path("/upload")
public class Check {

     @POST
     @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
     public Response validate(InputStream input) {
           ...
           return Response.ok().build();
     }
     ...
}
```

Hope these helps.